# How can I use foreach loop inside a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, foreach, webdriver

I need to find all elements in the page by class and click them, then in each element, I need to find all other elements by class and click, how can I do that in an easy way? I tried using foreach loop inside foreach loop, but it did not work properly

```
var select2arrow = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("select2-arrow"));
foreach (IWebElement element in select2)
{
    try
    {
        element.Click();
        var select2title = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("title"));
        foreach (IWebElement element in select2title )
        {
            try
            {
                element.Click();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         if (TestRunner.LogTestReports)
         {
                    driver.SaveScreenshot(ex);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_but it did not work properly_" -- What did not work?

Comment: Your code won't compile, you can't have a `try` with a `catch` block.

Answer (score 6):

The problem originates from the fact you are using the same name `element` as an iterator for both of the loops. You also break the try-catch block.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Gnqz answer, in `foreach (IWebElement element in select2)` you iterate over `select2` when the elements are in `select2arrow`.

You also don't have `catch` in the inner `try` block.